# Как писать невыплаченный, неотмеченный, неокрашенный

Tags: орфография

НЕ - это частица или предлог в данных словах? Писать месте или отдельно?

Comment: Нужен контекст. Нежелательны опечатки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильный вопрос: НЕ - это частица или приставка?

НЕ в  одиночных причастиях в полной форме  "невыплаченный, неотмеченный, неокрашенный" **является приставкой и пишется слитно.**

Сравнить: **не выплаченный вовремя долг, долг не выплачен.**  При наличии зависимого слова или краткой формы частица НЕ с причастием пишется раздельно.